# Month names in asp.net chart controls?

Tags: asp.net

I am using chart control, from database i am binding the data to the chart control, here problem is i am binding month names to the

`"XAxis" (January, February....)`

but on "Xaxis" alternative month names are showing like January March May, in this manner i want to display every month on the "Xaxis".

Please guide me if it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is some labels are not being shown due to size limitations.
You can force chart to show all labels on X axis by setting Interval property to 1.

```
ChartAreaID.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval=1
```